# Duplicate results from Rails search (Railscast #111)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a weird result when doing a search I've implimented from Railscast #111 (Advanced Search).

The search results are coming through OK from the entries that I have, but when the result is more than 1 (Iv'e only tested for two results) - it doubles the results. So when I expect two results, I get 4 (rendering out in a table).

The weird part is that when I expect 1 result, it only renders the 1 result.

I have a feeling it has something to do with my 'Search.rb' file which gives the search parameters. Can someone else shed some light on why this would be giving duplicate results?

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  def entries
    @entries ||= find_entries
  end

private

  def find_entries
    entries = Entry.order(:firstname)
    entries = entries.where("firstname like ?", "%#{firstname}%") if firstname.present?
    entries = entries.where("lastname like ?", "%#{lastname}%") if lastname.present?
    entries
  end
end
```

I am searching by either firstname or lastname, but the entries have more fields in them.

Comment: Are you sure you're not displaying them twice in the views?

Comment: That's what I thought, but why would only 1 result show when it returns one result and when it is more than 1 result, then it duplicates them

Comment: My opinion was, your first where retrieves two records then your second where also retrieves two records

Comment: To try debugging the SQL, you can use `#to_sql` : `entries.to_sql`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def find_entries
    entries = Entry.order(:firstname)
    if !firstname.blank?
        entries = entries.where("firstname like ?", "%#{firstname}%")
        if !lastname.blank?
            entries = entries.where("lastname like ?", "%#{lastname}%")
        end
    else
        if !lastname.blank?
            entries = entries.where("lastname like ?", "%#{lastname}%")
        end
    end
    entries
end
```

Comment: Thanks mate - looks like the issue is in the view - my table is rendering as per how many results there are. Does this look right: http://pastebin.com/zH6wTeJ8

Comment: Actually don't worry I got it. My show.html.erb was using the line
<%=render :partial=> 'entry', :collection=>@search.entries%>
Which was rendering duplicate lines - I just made it say <%=render 'entry'%>
and that fixed the issue - thanks for the help